# Concatenating valarrays

Tags: c++, concatenation, valarray

I have some data stored in a `std::vector<std::vector<double>`. I used this to create a `std::valarray` from my `std::vector<std::vector<double>`.

```
std:valarray<double> corpX(corps_tmp[i].data(), corps_tmp[i].size());
```

With this new `std:valarray<double>` I create a `std::vector` of corpX, so I obtain an `std::vector<std:valarray<double>>`. Now I need to store also the first two values of each `std::valarray` in another `std::valarray`:

```
std:valarray<double> position_corps = \\ Concatenation of all the std::valarrays corpsX
```

How can I accomplish this in a simple way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
// assume: std::vector<std::valarray<double>> corpsX;
std::valarray<double> position_corps(corpsX.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < corpsX.size(); ++i) {
    position_corps[std::slice(2 * i, 2, 1)] = corpsX[i][std::slice(0, 2, 1)];
}
```